# Magento 2: different way get field of a collection

Tags: magento2, collection, magic-getter

I have this helper class in Magento 2:

```
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_countryFactory;

    public function __construct(
         \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
    )
    {
         $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
    }

    public function getCountryIsoCode($country = 'US')
    {
          $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->getCollection();
          $country->addFieldToFilter('country_id', array('eq' => country));

          $countryCode = $country->getFirstItem()->getIso3Code());
          $countryCode2 = $country->getFirstItem()->getData('iso3_code'));

          // $countryCode => null
          // $countryCode2 => 'USA'

          return $countryCode;
     }
}
```

The function **getCountryIsoCode()** has an example as parameter ('US').
I don't why the **getIso3Code()** doesn't work.
Instead the **getData()** works perfectly.

In Magento2 there aren't "php magic function to get database table field" anymore?
Is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the `3` in the name.
I just tested and the magic getter does not play well with digits in the name.
The method `getIso3Code` does not exist, so, instead the method `__call` is called that is defined in `Magento\Framework\DataObject`.
The `get` part looks like this.

```
$key = $this->_underscore(substr($method, 3));
$index = isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null;
return $this->getData($key, $index);
```

the `_underscore` transforms the method name into the data key needed.
Here is the line that matters.

```
$result = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/([A-Z]|[0-9]+)/', "_$1", $name), '_'));
```

I just ran this code on http://phpfiddle.org/ :

```
$name = 'iso3_code';
echo strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/([A-Z]|[0-9]+)/', "_$1", $name), '_'));
```

and to my surprise it showed `iso_3_code` but you expected `iso3_code`.

Comment: This time I beat you :-)

Comment: Yep. Nice work. I already +1'd your answer.

Answer (score 9):

No Magento 2 also uses get/set magic methods. If you want to see those magic. Please try this:

```
$countryId = $country->getFirstItem()->getCountryId();
echo $countryId;
```

This will output the `country_id` value of first object as per your code.

So now the question is what happends with the call `getIso3Code()`. Well, here is the twist. Magento's magic getter will interpret this call as `iso_3_code` which is obviously undefined, hence you get `null` as result.

Why Magento treats this call in this way because, it uses `preg_replace()` method internally to retrieve the real  code  from the magic getter we are using. This means, when you call `getCountryId()`, Magento has an internal logic that will trace out the real code which you are looking for is `country_id`. This same internal logic will fail in case of `getIso3Code()` due to the occurrence of that number `3`.

So in this particular case, it is better to use `getData('iso3_code')` call.

Hope that will give you a clear picture.